# UIButton subclass with cap insets automatically applied

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton

OK, I thought I had a bright idea. A UIButton with cap insets automatically applied to background images.

```
@implementation JLTCapInsetButton

- (void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state
{
    CGFloat leftRight = (image.size.width - 1) / 2;
    CGFloat topBottom = (image.size.height - 1) / 2;
    UIEdgeInsets insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(topBottom, leftRight, topBottom, leftRight);
    UIImage *capInsetImage = [image resizableImageWithCapInsets:insets];

    [super setBackgroundImage:capInsetImage forState:state];
}

@end
```

This doesn't work because IB doesn't use `-setBackgroundImage:forState:`. My fix for this was to use `-awakeFromNib`.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [self JLT_fixBackgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self JLT_fixBackgroundImageForState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [self JLT_fixBackgroundImageForState:UIControlStateDisabled];
    [self JLT_fixBackgroundImageForState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [self JLT_fixBackgroundImageForState:UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [self JLT_fixBackgroundImageForState:UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateDisabled];
}

- (void)JLT_fixBackgroundImageForState:(UIControlState)state
{
    UIImage *backgroundImage = [self backgroundImageForState:state];

    if (backgroundImage)
        [self setBackgroundImage:backgroundImage forState:state];
}
```

This doesn't work because `[self backgroundImageForState:state]` always returns a value if an image was set for `UIControlStateNormal`.

Is there a clean way of hooking the setting of background images when decoding? Is there a clean way of detecting if a state has a background image and not just the implied image from the base state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about keeping a reference to the image which has been applied for UIControlStateNormal prior to your fix? For the subsequent control states, just check if the image is the same before applying your fix and if it is, skip fixing the image for that state...

Comment: I finally got back to this. I tested your recommendation and it worked. Yay!

Comment: Cool, glad it helped! Thanks for getting back to me :)